# Will my saved bookmarks and other data on Chrome be lost if I upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Will my saved bookmarks and extensions on Chrome be lost if I upgrade to Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

No, if you perform a successful system upgrade, your Chrome bookmarks and extensions (with their configuration) won't get cleared or overwritten.

*You should however remember to have a current backup before starting the process.*

---

On top of that you can set up a Google account and sign-in from Chrome to have your bookmarks and extensions stored in the cloud and be automatically restored (synchronised) to each of your devices.

However, this mechanism **will not** preserve the settings defined in the extensions' configuration. For example, if you use a cookie-whitelisting add-on and define your own whitelist, Chrome synchronisation will not preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

All Google Chrome data, including bookmarks, can be synchronized with Google.  If you enable sync, you will not lose your bookmarks and "other data" (as long as other data means Chrome data)

[You can find more information here.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

**Choose what to sync & how to protect it**

By default, when you sign in to Chrome, all your Chrome data will be synced to your Google Account. This includes bookmarks, history, passwords, and other information.

If you don't want to sync everything, you can also select what types of Chrome data to sync.

1. On a trusted computer, open Chrome and sign in.
2. At the top right, click the icon you see: Menu [image] or More [image].
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Under "Sign in," click **Advanced sync settings**.
5. Choose the information you want to sync:

   - To sync all data, click the Down arrow [image] and then **Sync everything**.
   - To choose what gets synced, click the Down arrow [image] and then **Choose what to sync**. Then check the boxes you want.
6. Under "Encryption options," choose how to protect your information:

   - **Encrypt synced passwords with your Google credentials** means that any synced passwords are kept secure by Google with your Google sign-in information.
   - **Encrypt all synced data with your own sync passphrase** means that any synced passwords plus all your other Chrome data are kept secure by a passphrase. No one can read your encrypted data unless they know the passphrase.
7. Click **OK**.